# A strange char appears at the first of my char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am making a Morse code converter, it's done, I solved the problem , but I do not understand it.
[picture represents the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKeuF.png)

This is some of the code:

```
string txt,result;
int x;
cout << "Enter the text you want to convert\n";
getline  (cin,txt);
x = txt.size();
char text[x];
strcat(text,txt.c_str());

cout<<"txt = "<<txt<<"\n"<<"text = "<<text<<endl;
```

I just want to know what is that `char`, and why it appears.

Comment: Posting what can be posted as text as image isn't good.

Comment: The bad character is random and followed by a '\0' by pure luck. Use `strcpy`, not `strcat`. Also `x` should be `txt.size() + 1` (for the ending `'\0'`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You didn't initialize `text`, so it has an indeterminate value. The strange characters came from somewhere of your memory in typical case. Initialize it before using. I think using `strcpy()` instead of `strcat()` is better in this case.
- Variable-length array is not supported in standard C++. I suggest you should use `new[]` instead.
- Do not forget to allocate space for terminating null-character.

Try this:

```
string txt, result;
int x;
cout << "Enter the text you want to convert\n";
getline(cin, txt);
x = txt.size() + 1; // +1 for terminating null character
char *text = new char[x];
strcpy(text, txt.c_str());

cout << "txt = " << txt << "\n" << "text = " << text << endl;

// do some other work with text

// after finished using text
delete[] text;
```

Answer (score 3):

`strcat` appends to a char array by searching for the end of the destination string (by looking for the null terminator) and then writing the additional characters there.

However, you've got an array of uninitialized memory, so the actual place where the string will be concatenated is indeterminate. You can either say:

```
text[0] = 0;
strcat(text, txt.c_str());
```

or just:

```
strcpy(text, txt.c_str());
```

Also, you can't initialize an array using a non-const variable, so you should either allocate the memory using new:

```
text = new char[x];
```

or just use a `std::string` and modify it as you go:

```
std::string text = txt;
```